# Develop asp.net application for windows server on linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono

I use linux and I am not willing to switch to windows. I need to create asp.net application for windows server with people working with visual studio on windows. I would like to work from my linux machine. I have heard about mono. Can I get some instructions and suggestions?

Note that the application will be deployed on windows.

Comment: You are severely handicapping yourself by refusing to work in the target OS. My advice is to get one of the “people working with visual studio on windows” to do the project.

Comment: Can I not do it with mono?

Comment: You can try mono but may run into compatibility issues. What about a VM from within Linux?

Comment: I could do that but I want to be able to program in vim and use shell scripting and also avoid visual studio if possible.

Comment: Alternatively write everything in Linux on vim, then deploy on Windows for testing?

Comment: @MikeS159, that's exactly what I want to do, and I thought it would be nice if I could test and debug easily as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way or another you are probably going to have to use Windows at some point. Even if everything runs fine under mono you will still need to check that it does on Windows.

You could set up a virtual machine on Linux running Windows, or have a separate machine for testing. If you are working in a team where someone else is responsible for most of the testing you could avoid that too.

Start by installing mono with `apt-get install mono-complete`. It would probably be easiest to get Visual Studio to setup the project. Hopefully you are using some form of version control, so you can push the code and pull it to your Linux machine. You can write the code on Linux in your preferred text editor and test it running under mono. Finally deploy it back to the Windows machine/VM to verify that it works as expected on your target platform.

You can check which features are currently fully, partially or not supported in mono here:

http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/

http://www.go-mono.com/status/

Comment: Thank you. Can I not create the project in mono?

Comment: There is no reason you can't, but some Visual Studio projects have quite a few files. Windows Form applications for example generate quite a few files for code and the layout. I believe Mono Develop can also setup projects, but doing it all just from a text editor might be difficult. http://www.monodevelop.com/